# Minimum permissions for postgres server dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Sql request to create a user with the minimum rights necessary for the full backup of the server postgres (without data)

Comment: What do you mean with "without data"? A backup without data is not a backup

Comment: task to unload rights and schemes of the postgres server without data